# Rails rejects my database.yml with "'postgresql' database is not configured"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have tried everything I have read on the internet but cannot seem to get it to work. I am trying to set it up on a new project. Here is my database.yml file:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: timetracker_development
pool: 5
username: postgres
password:
host: localhost

test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: timetracker_test
pool: 5
username: postgres
password:
host: localhost

production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: timetracker_production
pool: 5
username: timetracker
password:
```

And the error i get on my web page:

```
'postgresql' database is not configured. Available: ["development", "adapter", "encoding", "database", "pool", "username", "password", "host", "test", "production"]
```

I installed postgress via brew and then did the init command and when I type the start command all it says is "server starting". Does this mean it did or didn't start? Anyone know how I can get this to work?

Comment: What is this `database.yml`, and what is it for? I have used postgresql for 15 years, and never had any such `database.yml` on my computer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala This is the file in my rails project, probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: I think you have indented your `database.yml` wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Indenting is significant in YAML.

```
blah:
blah2: 1
```

means a different thing to:

```
blah:
    blah2: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how your database.yml should look like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: timetracker_production
  pool: 5
  username: timetracker
  password:
```